# Can you get the current user's phone # and contact details through the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

As far as I can tell, I can only get the entire address book, but there is no way to know which (if any) contact is the contact information for the owner of the phone, i.e. the phone # of the phone itself.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Perhaps by triangulating some data the SDK makes available?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
CFShow([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"]);
```